# @ManyToMany Duplicate Entry Exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have mapped a bidirectional many-to-many exception between the entities Course and Trainee in the following manner:

```
Course
{
    ...
    private Collection<Trainee> students;
    ...
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = lesson.domain.Trainee.class,
        cascade = {CascadeType.All}, fetch = {FetchType.EAGER})
    @Jointable(name="COURSE_TRAINEE",
        joincolumns = @JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TRAINEE_ID"))
    @CollectionOfElements
    public Collection<Trainee> getStudents() {
        return students;
        }
    ...
}


Trainee
{
    ...
    private Collection<Course> authCourses;
    ...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.All}, fetch = {FetchType.EAGER},
        mappedBy = "students", targetEntity = lesson.domain.Course.class)
    @CollectionOfElements
    public Collection<Course> getAuthCourses() {
        return authCourses;
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of creating a table where the Primary Key is made of the two foreign keys (imported from the table of the related two entities), the system generates the table "COURSE_TRAINEE" with the following schema:

[image]

I am working on MySQL 5.1 and my App. Server is JBoss 5.1.
Does anyone guess why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Bence Olah: the primary key constraint for (`COURSE_ID`, `TRAINEE_ID`) pair is not created because your mapping doesn't say that these pairs are unique. You need to  change `Collection`s to `Set`s in your code in order to express this restriction, and primary key will be created.

Answer (score 2):

Use either @CollectionOfElements **OR** @ManyToMany. Don't use both of them at the same time!
Be aware that @CollectionOfElements is Hibernate specific, while @ManyToMany is based on JPA standard.

Futher reading: 
http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html